# Does setting CURLOPT_URL force to create a second FTP connection?

Tags: libcurl

I want to open a connection with an FTP server and download 2 different files. Names are totally different and I cannot use wildcards.

I expected I could set the hostname and the file, then call `curl_easy_perform`, then set the file again and call `curl_easy_perform` one last time.

However it seems I have to use the `CURLOPT_URL` which includes both the hostname and the filename.

My fear is that the following code (lacks the error checking just to be short here):

```
...
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://myserver//foo.dat");
curl_easy_perform(handle);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://myserver//bar.png");
curl_easy_perform(handle);
```

opens the FTP connection twice, giving a lot of avoidable overhead.

So am I missing something here? Will libcurl notice that the hostname part is the same, thus avoiding to open the same connection twice? If not how can I open the connection only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling CURLOPT_VERSBOSE showed that:

```
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host 127.0.0.1
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 21 (#0)
* Request has same path as previous transfer
```

Also, wireshark showed that connection to port 21 is made only once and lasts throughout the whole transfer (including the two files).

However one connection per-file is made on another port because of the ftp passive mode, but I think this is not curl's fault.

Comment: The data part of an FTP transfer *MUST* use a second and fresh connection, that's due to how the protocol is designed.